# Fast Core Data Importing Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance, core-data, import

I use Core Data on my iPhone app to store about 1000 objects. Each object is assigned one of 5 different groups. Over time, the objects change groups, and within each group, the order of the objects in those groups change and is stored in an array.

I then take this array and use the attribute 'name' to store it to a plist. When I relaunch the app, my AppDelegate scans each object in the database, then compares it to the 'name' attribute in my plist. When this completes, I have 5 arrays of core data objects, sorted by group, each in the original saved order. The end result is good. The time it takes to complete this task is not.

I want to make this faster. If I could save the actual core data object array to my plist, I would do that. But I can only save attributes to it.

Apple has [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW1) on Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently, specifically, this code:

```
// get the names to parse in sorted order
NSArray *employeeIDs = [[listOfIDsAsString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]
        sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];

// create the fetch request to get all Employees matching the IDs
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[fetchRequest setEntity:
        [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:aMOC]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(employeeID IN %@)", employeeIDs]];

// make sure the results are sorted as well
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:
        [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"employeeID"
                ascending:YES] autorelease]]];NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *employeesMatchingNames = [aMOC
        executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

However, the fetchRequest sets a SortDescriptor and sorts using an 'employeeID' key. I tried this. I have an ID key attribute and can save the array index position when an object is added to a group. However, because objects are being added and removed from each group, the index of the object is constantly changing. So after each change, I would have to rescan each group and reset the index. To me, this would just move my speed problem to another part of my program.

My questions are: is there a better way to save the index position of objects in an array? or is there a different place I can store an array of core data objects? If I did the latter, though, because my app is already in the appStore, my understanding is if I add attributes or tables to the database, this can cause problems when a user upgrades.

I hope I explained this well. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making this way to complicated. The problem you want to solve i.e. ordering objects based on an attribute value, is a very common need e.g. every single tableview requires this type of ordering.

Ordering is why you can provide one or more sort descriptors to a fetch. In this case you want to order on an `employeeID` attribute so you just provide a sort that on that key. The array returned by the fetch will be sorted on that attribute.

When you add or remove objects, you just rerun the fetch again either directly or by using notifications. If you use a NSFetchedResultsController, this is all handled for you automatically.

If you need some kind of arbitrary ordering, say a user's list of favorites, then you need to model that arbitrary order directly in the data model. There are various means of doing so depending on the specific type of ordering needed.

Here is a good rule of thumb when designing with Core Data: ***If you have any other data structure to hold or order managed objects beyond the arrays returned by fetches, you've done something wrong.***

Used properly, Core Data can managed the entire data model without any external structures. If you find yourself welding extra data structures onto Core Data, then you've missed something in your data model design.

Answer (score 0):

On the iPhone there is no way to maintain an ordered collection other than storing an index.  That property is an integer, correct?

If you add attributes what happens is you need to set up the persistantStoreCoordinator in a way that it attempts an auto-migration.  If you never created another model version before though, this will be tricky.  You should try that and see if you can get it to work as you are probably going to have to do it someday...

My feeling on CoreData is that the migration is tricky enough you should always keep any user generated data to the side in something like a plist also, that you can re-build a data base from.  It sounds like you may already be doing that?  If so, you can check when you create the persistantStoreCoordinator if it has failed, and if so then erase the database that is there, create the persistantStoreCoordinator again, and populate that database from your plists.